# Example of Unit of System of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From this definition https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Unit_of_System_of_Sets :

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a system of sets. Let $U \in \mathcal{S}$ such that

$\forall A \in \mathcal{S}: A \cap U = A$

Then $U$ is the unit of $\mathcal{S}$. Note that, for a given system of sets, if $U$
exists then it is unique.

---

What is a non-trivial example? Does is mean that $U$ has to contain all elements from all subsets of $\mathcal{S}$? E.g. $\mathcal{S} = \{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}$ so $U = \{1, 2, 3\}$?

Comment: $A\cap U=A$ is the same statement as $A\subseteq U$ so it means that every $A\in\mathcal S$ must be a subset of $U$. Your example is not correct because needed is that also $U\in\mathcal S$.

Comment: It looks like they use the word unit because, under intersection, $U$ acts like a multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $A \cap U = A$ is equivalent to $A \subseteq U$.  Thus $U$ is the unit for $\mathcal{S}$ means that $U \in \mathcal{S}$ and $A \subseteq U$ for every $A \in \mathcal{S}$. So $U$ must contain all the elements of each member of $\mathcal{S}$.

Your example $\mathcal{S} = \{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}$ does not have a unit, because there is no set *in $\mathcal{S}$* that has each set in $\mathcal{S}$ as a subset.  On the other hand, if $\mathcal{S}' = \{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ then $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is the unit for $\mathcal{S}'$.

For another example, if $\mathcal{S} = \{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}$ then $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is the unit.  Note how important it is that the unit is actually in the system for the claim about uniqueness!